# Web scraping with VBA - Early Binding VS Late Binding of HTMLDocument Object

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to set up automatized update of stock values based on "https://finance.yahoo.com".

I need to use Late binding, which is not working, while early binding works just fine. Is there a way to fix it?

```
 Sub FetchFinanceInfoLateBinding()

    Dim XMLReq As Object
    Dim HTMLDoc As Object
    Dim post As Object, I&

    Set XMLReq = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    'Set HTMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    Set HTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA/cash-flow?p=BABA", False
    XMLReq.send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    Set post = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")(0)
    Debug.Print post.innerText


End Sub


Sub FetchFinanceInfoEarlyBinding()

    Dim XMLReq As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, I&

    XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA/cash-flow?p=BABA", False
    XMLReq.send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText


    Set post = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")(0)
    Debug.Print post.innerText

End Sub
```

As mentioned before, i would like to be able to use late binding while setting up this solution.

Comment: That's a known issue, late bound `htmlfile` uses IE version below 9, which doesn't support `.getElementsByClassName` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @omegastripes:

> late bound htmlfile uses IE version below 9, which doesn't support
>   .getElementsByClassName method

.

You could regex it out however:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FetchFinanceInfoLateBinding()
    Dim XMLReq As Object
    Dim HTMLDoc As Object
    Dim post As Object, I&

    Set XMLReq = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    Set HTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA/cash-flow?p=BABA", False
    XMLReq.send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    MsgBox GetValue(XMLReq.responseText, """regularMarketPrice"":{""raw"":[0-9.]+,""fmt"":""(\d+\.\d+)""}")

End Sub
Public Function GetValue(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As String
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = sPattern
        If .test(inputString) Then
            GetValue = .Execute(inputString).item(10).SubMatches(0)
        Else
           GetValue = vbNullString
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Try regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/e88MDn/1)

Comment: This Regex solution works. The only thing left for me is to understand how it works, Thank You!

Comment: The value is present in a script tag which is in the response. I specify a regex pattern that finds strings that matches that pattern. I index into returned matches to get the one required for latest value.